# Javascript ai jump platformer

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence

So i am trying to make a 2d platformer but i am having trouble with the ai. I can make the enemy follow me around perfectly when we start on the same platform but not when we start at the opposite side of the map like so.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJeNe.jpg

so i want the enemy to jump because there is no platform below. What would be the best way to let the ai know where and when to jump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think of the platforms as nodes that are connected. If you had a bottom platform, both top and bottom would be "choices" for the AI when it reaches the edge of the left/right platforms. There, your platform should contain data to which platforms is it connected to.

You might want to add some data on your platforms like level/height so the AI knows what it should do when it transitions from platform to platform, whether it should jump up to the next plaform or just drop down.